# Move (drag) divs from one list into multiple possible targets, and between targets as well

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

Like I try to explain in my image, I want to be able to drag items from the "items list" into any of the possible drop areas.

[image]

I also need to:
- Be able to drag items from one possible drop area to another.
- Be able to rearrange items inside each possible drop area.

I found some similar solutions here, but can´t find the right one.
Here is a code that comes close to my needs.

```
$(function () {
  $(".dropTarget").sortable({
      revert: true,
      receive: function(ev, ui){
          ui.item.remove();
      }
  });
  $("#itemlist div").draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".dropTarget",
      helper: function(ev, ui){
        return "<div>"+$(this).text()+"</div>";
      }
  });
});
```

Here is the working example: "http://jsfiddle.net/3wCHu/28/"

The problem with this code is that I can´t move items from one "drop area" to "another".
Also when moving an item from the "items list" to a drop area, this code "draws" a div, and fills it with the text of the item. But in my case, the items are more complex than just text.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, It turns out it´s quite easy.
Just have to use this code to choose what connect with

```
$(function () {
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").sortable({
                connectWith: "#items1,#items2,#items3",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                }
        });
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").disableSelection();
});
```

Here is a link with a working demo
http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui/sortable-connectwith.html